# Quality Gates 500 error

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using the [SonarQube quality gates plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quality+Gates+Plugin).

My project has SonarQube ID `com.my.package:my-project:origin/feature/WRAP-1-test` and URI `com.my.package:my-project:origin%2Ffeature%2FWRAP-1-test`.

In Jenkins, under `Quality Gates`, `Project Key`, I tried using both the ID and the URI.

However, on both occasions when I build the project, I am getting:

```
SonarQube analysis completed: SUCCESS
    quality.gates.jenkins.plugin.QGException: Expected status 200, got: 500. Response: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>SonarQube</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #666;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    }

    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 100%;
      color: #f00;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This file lives in public/500.html -->
<div class="dialog">
  <h1>We're sorry, but something went wrong.</h1>

  <p>Please try back in a few minutes and contact <a href="http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/">support</a> if the problem
    persists.</p>

  <p>
    <!-- SONAR-4447 Sometimes this error page is served as static html so we hide ruby code -->
    <a href="/">Go back to the homepage</a>
    <!-- -->
  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

    at quality.gates.sonar.api.SonarHttpRequester.executeGetRequest(SonarHttpRequester.java:59)
    at quality.gates.sonar.api.SonarHttpRequester.getAPIInfo(SonarHttpRequester.java:47)
    at quality.gates.sonar.api.QualityGatesProvider.getRequesterResult(QualityGatesProvider.java:34)
    at quality.gates.sonar.api.QualityGatesProvider.getAPIResultsForQualityGates(QualityGatesProvider.java:29)
    at quality.gates.jenkins.plugin.BuildDecision.getStatus(BuildDecision.java:20)
    at quality.gates.jenkins.plugin.QGPublisher.perform(QGPublisher.java:73)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1067)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Build step 'Quality Gates' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea why the call fails?

**EDIT**:

My logs contain the following 2 errors:

```
2017.02.14 15:25:48 ERROR web[AVoyVzS5I0AJ4yijAAU1][rails] Fails to execute http://localhost:9000/api/events?resource=com.my.package:my-project:origin/feature/WRAP-1-test&format=json&categories=Alert : undefined method `generate' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x2f8ea6a2>
```

And:

```
web.log:2017.02.14 15:25:48 ERROR web[AVoyVzS5I0AJ4yijAAU1][o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://localhost:9000/api/events?resource=com.my.package:my-project:origin/feature/WRAP-1-test&format=json&categories=Alert
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:470:in `JSON'
/Users/octavian/Downloads/sonarqube-6.2/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:48:in `jsonp'
/Users/octavian/Downloads/sonarqube-6.2/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:132:in `error_to_json'
/Users/octavian/Downloads/sonarqube-6.2/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:123:in `render_response'
```

My version of SonarQube is `6.2`.

Comment: 1) what does your server log say? 2) Consider [edit]ing your question to include the SonarQube version

Comment: I've updated my question with the errors from the log files.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, my steps for solving irwere:

1. open `sonarqube-6.2/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb`, and change to `ENV['GEM_PATH']=''`.
2. go to the folder where `sonar.sh` is  and run `unset GEM_PATH`
3. `sonar.sh restart`

The issue is caused by some incompatibilities with the installed version of ruby.